# Select ROI in equirectangular image

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, roi

I want to apply some image processing operations on an equirectangular image. (shown below)

[image: Equirectangular image]

For this purpose i want to select a region of interest such that the half circles on both ends (represented by green color) should be discarded whereas the area inside the red boundary should be considered.

[image]

Let the size of the image is X * Y , where X is width and Y is height. The radius of both circles will be X/(2*4). How can I select this ROI in openCV?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can propose a solution which involves a lot of geometry.

If you know the co-ordinates of points A,B,C,D as shown in the image below

[image]

You can calculate the co-ordinates of C1 and C2 using the method in this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128170023/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53027.html).
With the centers and the radius, the equation of the circle can be found and the image can be limited to the circumference of the circle. The green portion will have distance less than the radius so it can be neglected.